# React query dependency queries not feching data on first click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13, react-query

I am fetching data using react query. On submit click it successfully fetch postal data. and update the back variable but the problem is backdropData is not fetching and it show undefined. Again I click on button I show me the data. How can I fix this problem. Thank you

```
//Query
    const postalData = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["postalArea", postalCode],
        queryFn: () => GET_POSTAL_CODE(postalCode),
        enabled: !!postalCode,
    });

let back = postalData.data?.[0]["Reference to Admin - User Property"];

const backdropData = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["backdrop", back, getId],
    queryFn: () => GET_BACKDROP(back??'', getId),
    enabled: !!back,
});





const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = async (value: Inputs) => {
    console.warn('Sumitting Data')
    await postalData.refetch();
    console.warn(`Postal Data ${postalData.data?.[0]["Reference to Admin - User Property"]}`)
    await backdropData.refetch();

}
```